# What to do with information collected from PCI devices

Tags: pci, osdev

When an operating system enumerates the PCI bus it collects information from each PCI device. My question is, where does the operating system store this information? Does every operating system have a 64KB array sitting in RAM while it runs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PCI information gets stored into kernel data structures eg: struct resource which particularly stores the BAR's physically mapped addresses.

These would then be used by device drivers by first remapping them to virtual addresses and then accessing them.

Comment: What do you mean by "the BAR's physically mapped addresses"? Also, where are kernel structures stored? In RAM?

Comment: 1. The BAR's have a mapping into the RAM (physical memory). 2. Yes.